# nodejs refresh html after fetch promise stays pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I'm using express and nodejs and have trouble with and then method logging a promise that stays pending.

```
      edit().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Here is the edit function.

```
    async function edit(data, id) {
        let response = await fetch(config_url+'/subscriber/' + id, {
                headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
                method: 'PUT',
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
        let ret = await repsonse.json();
        return ret; 
    }
```

The rest api is express js.

```
Subscriber.edit = function (name, email, id, result) {
        sql.query("UPDATE subscribers SET name=?, email=? WHERE id = ?", [name, email, id], function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error: ", err);
                result(null, err);
            } else {
                console.log(res);
                result(res);
            }
        });
    };
```

The data changes in the database but below the res.send() line "subscriber changed successfully" in postman.

```
    exports.edit_subscriber = function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.params);
        console.log(req);
        console.log(res);
        Subscriber.edit(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.params.id, function(err, subscriber) {
            if (err) {
                res.sendStatus(err);
            }
            res.send({ message: 'Subscriber succesfully edited'});
        });
    };
```

Again why does my own async function return a Promise that is not resolved and stays pending in the console of chrome.

EXPRESS ERROR

```
    'access-control-allow-origin': [ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' ]
  }
}
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 1
}
/Users/[classified]/repos/[classified]]/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 1
}
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:241:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:232:8)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:607:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:717:5)
```

Comment: Try using async await in your express code also,and let me know

Comment: @warmachine it still changes the database but chrome says "PUT http://localhost:3000/subscriber/41 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
"

Comment: meaning express server is not running mate

Comment: @arunK I added the express error.

Comment: i have spotted few issues and posted in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to stringify the `res.send(JSON.stringify(json))`

```
exports.edit_subscriber = function (req, res) {
    ...
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Subscriber succesfully edited' }));
};
```

Also in the below code, you are passing the parameters to the callback incorrectly. The first parameter is `err`, second parameter is `result`. its not passed correctly.

```
Subscriber.edit = function (name, email, id, resultCallBack) {
  sql.query("UPDATE subscribers SET name=?, email=? WHERE id = ?", [name, email, id], function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      resultCallBack(err);
    } else {
      console.log(res);
      resultCallBack(null, res);
    }
  });
};
```

Also `res.sendStatus` accepts only status code.

```
res.sendStatus(400).send(JSON.stringify{message: 'error occured'});
```

hope this helps

Comment: I can't use ```resultCallBack``` (can't be found) but the missing else statement made my server not crash everytime an error happend. And the ```sendStatus(400)``` explained to me stuff as did the other stuff thanks a lot for that.

The problem is more ```then(data => console.log(data));``` not happening because data is empty when it is logged I think. It doesn't wait till it exists.

Answer (score 0):

you have typos and uneeded "let"

```
async function edit(data, id) {
        let response = await fetch(config_url+'/subscriber/' + id, {
                headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
                method: 'PUT',
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
        let ret = await repsonse.json();
        return ret; 
    }
```

**repsonse**.json() won't work.
No need to `let` if you don't modify them later. Also, JSON.stringify might fail and you don't have any trycatch block.

```
async function edit(data, id) {
        let serializedData = "";
        try {
          serializedData = JSON.stringify(data);
        catch (error) {
           // do something with error
        }
        const response = await fetch(config_url+'/subscriber/' + id, {
                headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
                method: 'PUT',
                body: serializedData
            });
        return response.json();
    }
```